# How to decode javascript variable value which contain html element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have one variable with some text and anchor tag element like

```
var success_msg = 'Please <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="popup-login" class="login" title="Login">login</a> to save your wishlist.';
```

Now this variable I am passing to ajax and this message display with popup on ajax success.

Ajax Code:

```
var success_msg = 'Please <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="popup-login" class="login" title="Login">login</a>+ to save your wishlist.';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASE_URL+"home/featherlightInfo",
    data: "success_msg="+success_msg,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#loading-div').hide(); // Hide Ajax loader
        $('#featherlightInfoPop').html(html);
        $.featherlight('#featherlightInfo');                    

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".featherlight-close").trigger("click");
        }, 5000);

        $('#feathre').addClass('login-feathre');
    }
});
```

Everythig is working perfect but in popup HTML I am getting anchor tag like this:

```
<a title="\&quot;Login\&quot;" class="\&quot;login\&quot;" id="\&quot;popup-login\&quot;" href="\&quot;javascript:void(0);\&quot;">login</a>`
```

One of the strange thing is that this code is working perfect from my local server.

I want this result: `Please <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="popup-login" class="login" title="Login">login</a> to save your wishlist.`

So what to do to get proper anchor element?

Comment: Sounds like it should be fixed server side, not client side

Comment: So you're passing a message to the server, that sends it back to the client, that alerts it?? What's the point?

Comment: Why not just send the html from the server-side? It's much cleaner and not complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `encodeURI` function of javascript:

```
var success_msg = 'Please <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="popup-login" class="login" title="Login">login</a>+ to save your wishlist.';
var encode_msg = encodeURI(success_msg);
```

[For more read documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

OR

You can pass a flag message in the ajax request and on the basis of that you can create this `'Please <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="popup-login" class="login" title="Login">login</a>+ to save your wishlist.';` HTML code on server side. This will be good practice.

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery `ajax`: When you sent data to the server, it will be converted into a query string, so the quotes is escaped.

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or an object of the form {key1: 'value1',
>   key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted
>   into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This
>   processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The
>   processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to
>   the server; in this case, change the contentType option from
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.